SwiftUI MapKit iOS 17 - MapCircles() with opacity are overlapping
I have a MapView from the new SwiftUI iOS 17 MapKit where I have two MapCirlces() next to each other. But the Circles are overlapping when I apply an opacity to it. My goal is to achieve the same opacity with both of the circles, even in the area where the Circles are overlapping. Initially I wanted to do it with a MKMapView and then trying to add a custom Overlay where I render all Circles in it and then Apply an Opacity on it on the Map. But as there now is a new SwiftUI MapKit Version with iOS 17, I started creating the Map with this Library. But I haven't really figured out how I can work with the new MapKit to achieve the same as I initially planed with MKMapView. And due to future adaption, deprecation of MKMapView and creating the App from scratch, I would prefer to stick with the new Version of MapKit.
So this would be a really basic Version of the Code I have right know:
Map {
    //Both of the circles are overlapping on one Point
    MapCircle().foregroundStyle(Color.blue.opacity(0.3)) //Circle1
    MapCircle().foregroundStyle(Color.blue.opacity(0.3)) //Circle2
}


If you draw the circles as fully opaque, you can then apply an opacity level to the whole Map. If the same map is shown in the background, it gives the appearance you want. But... I couldn't find a way to synchronize the two maps. So this workaround is only likely to be useful if map interaction is disabled.
